# MFC Debug Assertion Failed wincore.cpp/ afxwin.inl

Tags: mfc

When I call the the Domodal, to create the dialog, I get the debug assertion failed.
I have inserted the break point at starting of InitDialog of my function, but before that it fails. curser will not come to the my Init function, Before that it fails.
How to solve this problem.

This is not fixed, some times it works fine but sometimes fails.

Comment: What is the assertion that is failing?

Comment: Does it go to constructor of class? Did you pass the correct resource ID?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a resource ID that could not be loaded, or a control on the dialog that could not be created. Change the property of the dialog 'fail on child creation' or something like that to 'false' to see if that is the issue. If it is, and your dialog launches, it's easy to see which control is missing.

Otherwise, post the code at that location, and your call stack.